How to increase topic rate higher
Hi I am wondering if I can increase topic rate.
Here is two nodes, one is about lidar which send 'sensor_msgs::msg::Laserscan' data for 10hz and other one sends 'geometry_msg::msg::Twist' based on Laserscan data. and I want to send Twist data about 20 ~ 30 hz
    class ObjectDetectionNode : public rclcpp::Node
    {
    public:
        ObjectDetectionNode() : Node("object_detection_ros2_node")
        { 
    laser_sub = this>create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>("scan_raw", 
            10, std::bind(&ObjectDetectionNode::msgCallback_lidar, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    cmd_vel_pub = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>("cmd_vel", 30);

    timer = this->create_wall_timer(33ms, std::bind(&ObjectDetectionNode::timer_callback, this));

    private:
        /************************** Functions *****************************/
    
        void msgCallback_lidar(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg);
        void timer_callback();

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr lidar_cloud{new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>};
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr out_cloud{new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>};
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>::SharedPtr laser_sub;
    rclcpp::Publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>::SharedPtr cmd_vel_pub;
    };


    void ObjectDetectionNode::msgCallback_lidar(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg)
    {
        sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan scan_msg = *msg;
        lidar_cloud->points.clear();
    
        for (size_t i = 0; i < scan_msg.ranges.size(); i++)
        {
            double angle = (scan_msg.angle_increment) * i + scan_msg.angle_min;
            double range = scan_msg.ranges[i];
    
            if(std::isnan(range)) 
            {
                range = 0;
            }
    
            double lidar_x = range * cos(angle);
            double lidar_y = range * sin(angle);
    
            lidar_cloud->points.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(lidar_x, lidar_y, 0.0));
        }
        lidar_cloud->width = lidar_cloud->points.size();
        lidar_cloud->height = 1;
        lidar_cloud->is_dense = true;
    }

    void ObjectDetectionNode::timer_callback()
    {
        double linear_ = 0.0, angular_ = 0.0;
        geometry_msgs::msg::Twist twist;
        std::vector<ObjInfo> obj_info_vector;
    
        if (lidar_cloud->points.size() == 0 )
            return;

        .....
        // twist value is calculated base on laserscan data  
        .....        
        
         twist.angular.z = angular_;
         twist.linear.x = linear_;

         cmd_vel_pub->publish(twist);
    }

this is part of my code.
Topic "scan_raw" is 10 hz and this is sent from YDLidar
[https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros2_driver/tree/humble][1]
and question is

"scan_raw" is only 10hz but can i change "cmd_vel" rate 20~30hz in this node?

If question 1 is impossible then it seems like to change the code of Lidar but Lidar's hardware limit is 10 hz. Is there any solution?



As I understand your questions:

Yes, seems you can just reduce the period of timer_callback() set in create_wall_timer() to publish the /cmd_vel more often. Note however that you may publish several times the same commands as the laserscan won't always change between two calls of timer_callback() as the period is smaller than laserscan publication period, may not be what you want (to be in sync you may compute and publish /cmd_vel in the laser callback).

Some YDLidars have the scan frequency and so laserscan publication rate settable via the parameter frequency described here, but the higher the frequency the lesser the angular resolution (eg. like on YDLidar TG15, can go up to 12Hz). Check the datasheet of your model to see if the scan frequency can be adjusted on your model.



you mean then i have to calculate /cmd_vel in "void ObjectDetectionNode::msgCallback_lidar(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg)" ?
